# How do I get ENS domain transfers using Alchemy Transfers API (alchemy_getAssetTransfers)?

Tags: json-rpc, ens, alchemy, transfers-api

I'm using the Transfers API (Tx History) -- Internal Eth Transfers, but i cant get ENS txns in its response.

Here is the json rpc request I'm making:

```json
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 0,
  "method": "alchemy_getAssetTransfers",
  "params": [
    {
      "fromAddress": "0xDce63CBee5E3f5d30729b777a11385B58b711a3c",
      "excludeZeroValue": true,
      "withMetadata": true,
      "category": [
        "internal",
        "erc20",
        "erc721",
        "erc1155",
        "specialnft"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect the ENS domain transfer that shows up in this transaction hash (`0xc97431eec5791405982b3d1873ed38062e5ea2542997aad9468efb28075bc88f`) to appear in the api call response, but it isn't there.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alchemist here

There are two things you can do to repro/debug:

### 1. Use the [Alchemy Composer](https://alchemy.com/?a=97465efb95):

You can use the composer to issue quick requests directly in the browser. It looks like this:

[image: Alchemy Composer in the dashboard]

You can then fill in the `fromAddress`, `withMetadata`, `categories`, etc. fields and then hit "Send Request" to get a response. Then you can manually check the response.

This works well if the expected response is small and easy to parse, but if it isn't, then we should try option 2.

### 2. Write a script:

As shown in the [Alchemy Transfers API documentation](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/enhanced-apis/transfers-api), you have the option of writing a Javascript `fetch` or `axios` call using json rpc to query for Transfers events. When the response comes back, you can add some logic to test for the specific events you're expecting.

---

To solve your actual root problem though, I noticed that the ENS transfer transaction you shared has `0xDce63CBee5E3f5d30729b777a11385B58b711a3c` as the TO address, whereas in your `alchemy_getAssetTransfers` request, you set `0xDce63CBee5E3f5d30729b777a11385B58b711a3c` to be the FROM address.

Once you make the switch, you can see ([example Alchemy composer request](https://dashboard.alchemyapi.io/composer?share=eJyVWF9v2jAQ.y555gGKGB1vwMZaqWtR2.Vh1YSMc4Sojo0cp4Cqfvc5CaXO_RzoSxvd78.ZPtu58BbxNUtlNOp2Iglmq.RL9ZyBWav4lmUQjSIm_Bqy.SIBM85zMI_ayXwFOo8_iHcbkyqZR6Pnt_iVieKUSrAliFbOe4d0elQvIMdCqC2THGgnxGlzmjBRcgJDalLafH6DYTEzrMXnSAn5lFNnvFzHe_CQbkxoVATR9VwqXa1nYQujHYtmnFBMC61BmrlWG5UDIcWEsMcTE6mdrGoUO0ghfO6VMlcsX.vyI0KoHtJE2s0zDkibsKu3m3jBOFeFbKx6I4z5S6H4y22RLRtLhRGs4kwIRK9CHq88ltcxph6imA25STNm4BfDw3cRrFoBXKW5LcEeiRwAaxKWz3XaOHqNsMcHczhBWPEJUJpyCSd7VEcCDGvJ0nhwSE_cQRIO6Z1TOi33T_tcAuTzvVvnGqQT.lMVE4WqogR7lgoDerpmMmncoSQc1N_oJCiuMEJJa0Jse2OplU_vwwSfuH0wQqge7IFhCYyNL.uECJ1Tn8m_qliZYSzjaxnDzjc7wT8rQ70DvpIDKU5loZfPp7T7VPu11aZmtLscDmurzwfnLKf8sCbnOB65hPMfyQWcVfMg84TrqTq3cEPOhzvkOJSAqUc7xy90j4WI2DNjO.saUjo1_xnAHLT.QiQp2EfCtkpTX0LIAYGENiQLK_Yg41QmzvYJeQSZ2HWjlVFciSfb8lgWcsIoVuc2zT3bOmmQAUHwPPaS26Fi4SGK2YVMZW5sL0TOHKOuunpDSaPtMIhGnEKReiaU0ritacaR4oZp_04zY79nJECkvZ090sN0AV_DklQRgjVTeqqEAFwzEkb6u23ZH7c4UISQR.XVE5DXmKu0H58LYXtOsHV2d0wzjhWv3t52oy57w8oT39behRiuS7mLoO7vHaUb9dmo43eCPleHThwJE3rYCFbfkA7RnWU7L_TYOiiP4bvYv0G9i7nKLSz7Cy7S8lvRKzMBetp8zfpYUsXe.3XKarPMfoMWtjMtf7WAHRdFDH9BqyoajYwuoBNx__2UlB9Co2fLsTePZGU1U3l8BM0vuvX.4UWvfuj1BoPIZllplY3jWENus0QW26ZmfTzjhxRGfVK6ux8cvvWnE4DBz.5qEPe7w4vvy_FwyHq9.uVgMrhcDns91ud2Fu..AdxNW0o-)) that the response will include your desired ENS transfer event:

```json
{
  "blockNum":"0xe04a89" 
  "hash":"0xc97431eec5791405982b3d1873ed38062e5ea2542997aad9468efb28075bc88f"
  "from":"0x283af0b28c62c092c9727f1ee09c02ca627eb7f5"
  "to":"0xdce63cbee5e3f5d30729b777a11385b58b711a3c"
  "value":0.000353526461158219
  "erc721TokenId":NULL
  "erc1155Metadata":NULL
  "tokenId":NULL
  "asset":"ETH"
  "category":"internal"
  "rawContract":{...}
  "metadata":{...}
}
```

Hope that helps!